# iCloud enabled app freezes when toggling iCloud on/off in iOS 7.1 Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, icloud

An app with newly added iCloud support (basically just entitlements string added and Xcode iCloud switch toggled, without any iCloud related code yet) freezes when I run it on device and toggle an app-named switch in system `Settings > iCloud > Documents and Data`

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x3b3a7a58 in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x3b3a7858 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x3067989a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x30678006 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x305e2f4e in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x305e2d32 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x35504662 in GSEventRunModal ()
#7  0x32f2e16c in UIApplicationMain ()
#8  0x0005013c in main at main.m:16
```

Xcode reports this line in main.m:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); < Thread 1: signal SIGKILL
```

**Update**
Ok. I got it, this is the standard iOS behavior. When the user changes that setting the app receives SIGKILL signal. But why? What is reason behind that?

Comment: What do you mean by app freezes?

Comment: Stops responding and XCode shows 8 crash threads, one of them I pasted in the question.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: any update on this one? I'm seeing the same strange behavior.